# SQL Server 2017 stand-alone stuck

Tags: sql-server-2017, ssms-2017

[image]

It's second time i was install SQL server 2017 on window 10

Getting stuck on installation progress error as below

sql_inst_mpyConfigAction_Install_Confignonrc_Cpu64

Comment: How long is it "stuck" there? Have you had a look at the installation logs?

Comment: issue resolved juts remove all component and install again

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue just now. Waiting for about 30 min worked for me. I assume it was downloading Python or R packages under the hood, so disabling those options from installation could help.